# Scheduled Local and Push Notification in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutterflow

I am switching back and forth between Flutterflow and Flutter to build my app because of the limitations of what Flutterflow will allow. At this point,

I have Push Notification from FF working. So I have a start, but now I need to be able to schedule notifications based on specific times and events. For that, I am looking at either

a. flutter_local_notifications 15.1.0+1: OR b. awesome_notifications 0.7.4+1

If you can please help with the following, I would greatly appreciate it.

Can I get Local Notification working without an external package?

If not, would you recommend one of these packages or a different one?

Any resources - documentation, videos that you would recommend.

Thanks in advance.

FlutterFlow does not allow, at least not apparent to me, a way to schedule notifications. They have the ability to trigger notification and I am exploring it, but it is not very flexible.
I would like to be able to eventually have both Push Notification and Local Notification for different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to see the talk (and the [article](https://guillaume.bernos.dev/how-to-handle-all-kinds-of-notifications/)) of Guillaume Bernos, on how to handle notification.

To keep it short: To handle all sorts of notifications (foreground/background/local/pushed etc...) it's better to use a package that goes in-depth and allows you to handle correctly notifications on both iOS and Android since notifications are pretty different on both platforms.
To do exactly that, I would definitively use FLN (flutter_local_notifications), and customize the notifications with this package.

Comment: Thanks much. I will start as you suggested.